Opening a new terminal and executing command from JetBrains Plugin
I trying to develop a JetBrains Plugin using Java that will open a new terminal and execute a command in that terminal.
I have the following code:
try {
    var commandLine = new GeneralCommandLine($command);
    commandLine.setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ShellTerminalWidget shellTerminalWidget = TerminalToolWindowManager.getInstance(project).createLocalShellWidget(".", "NewTab");
    shellTerminalWidget.executeCommand(commandLine.getCommandLineString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handling error here;
}

When I debug this from inside the IntelliJ, it is working, but when I create a plugin from it and add that plugin to PhpStorm and try to use it, nothing is happening... I don't get the new terminal and I don't know what is going on.
Any idea?
